# SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=$_GET['id'] AND user1=$user OR user2=$user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a similar facebook style messaging system (conversations).

This is the conversation table.

```
DESCRIBE conversation;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| c_id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_one | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_two | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip       | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now before the user can read a conversation, I need to check if the conversation (c_id) exists, and if the user is the owner of the given conversation id. **What is the best possible way to write this query**?

Example of what I have, which is not working:

```
$cid = intval($_GET['cid']);

$conv = $this->db->fetchRow('SELECT c_id FROM `conversation` WHERE 
        user_one=? OR 
        user_two=? AND 
        c_id=?', 
        array($this->user->id, $this->user->id, $cid));

if ($conv) {
// get the conversation replies etc..
}
```

Comment: What happens if you want to have more than 2 users in a conversation?

Comment: What error are you getting? Or why is it not working?

Comment: Conversations should be a join table between Users and Conversation. You would store the Conversation ID, the user ID and the text in that table so that you can reference the full conv from either users or conversations. THis also allows you to have more than 2 people in a conversation. Also, lose the backticks (`conversation`)

Comment: Missing a closing parentheses. $cid = intval($_GET['cid'];

Comment: @SamDufel Is designed so only 2 users can be on a conversation.

Comment: @Cheruvian Even if the conversation id doesn't exists in the database, the if($conv) part gets executed which shouldnt.

Comment: Just wondering why the question was downvoted? I'm asking for help on how to write the query part (WHER AND OR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of problems.

One is that you seem to have overlooked that `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`. So the logic of your condition works as if you had written it this way:

```
WHERE user_one=? OR (user_two=? AND c_id=?)
```

Whereas I would guess that you intended the logic to work this way:

```
WHERE (user_one=? OR user_two=?) AND c_id=?
```

But if that's how you intended it to work, I wonder why you need to search for the user id's at all, since the condition on `c_id=?` will select only one row (or zero rows if there's no match), because it's searching for one specific primary key value.

Comment: So that's what I was doing wrong, the logic of my conditions :(. Thank you, that did the job!